# Structure group simply connected implies first chern class vanishes

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles

The situation is something like this:

Let $M$ be a compact complex surface and $TM$ its tangent bundle.
Assume that the structure group of $TM$ can be reduced to a simply connected, simple Lie group. Then the first Chern class of $M$ vanishes.

I am not sure if all of the stated assumptions are neccessary or if further assumptions are required, as I encountered this as part of a longer proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. $M$ does not need to be compact or a surface, the simply connected Lie group does not need to be simple, and this is true more generally for any complex vector bundle, not just a complex tangent bundle. The point is that if $G$ is simply connected then $BG$ is $2$-connected, so the pullback of the universal first Chern class $c_1 \in H^2(BU(n), \mathbb{Z})$ to $BG$ vanishes because $H^2(BG, \mathbb{Z})$ vanishes.

Comment: So for $TM=f^*BU$ we have $c_1(TM)=f*c_1(BU)$ and as $c_1(BU)\in H^2(BG;\mathbb Z)=0$, the conclusion follows?  I am not very familiar with the homotopy groups. Why does $\pi_2(BG)=0$ imply $H^2(BG)=0$?

Comment: $2$-connected means that $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ vanish as well. So $BG$ is in particular simply connected, so by the Hurewicz theorem $H_2(BG, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \pi_2(BG) = 0$, and then by universal coefficients $H^2(BG, \mathbb{Z}) = 0$ as well.

Comment: If you instead want to assume that $G$ is simple then you can use a much more concrete argument. Namely: the first Chern class of a complex vector bundle $V$ classifies its determinant line bundle. You can write down an explicit cocycle describing this line bundle from an explicit cocycle describing $V$ by applying the determinant $\det : GL_n(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ pointwise. But the precomposition of $\det$ with any inclusion $G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ of a simple Lie group is trivial by simplicity.

Comment: Somehow I missed your second comment. Could you expand on it a little? So I want to calculate the first chern class of a vector bundle $E$ with structure group $G$. I know that it suffices to calculate the first chern class of the determinant line bundle. If $E$ has transition functions $\psi\in G$, then $\det(E)$ has transition functions $\det \psi$. You claim that simplicity of $G$ implies that $\det \psi=1$. Why is that, and how does this relate to $G$ being simply connected?

Comment: @klirk: the determinant is a homomorphism out of $G$, so by simplicity its kernel is either all of $G$ or trivial.